# Non type-variable argument in the Constraint: Enum A => Ord A

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am new to Haskell.

I want to implement **Ord** class for a Custom Data type using **Enum** class.

It works fine if I implement **Enum** class and use the **fromEnum** function directly in the implementation of **compare** function required for **Ord** class.

But as **Type Signatures** and **Type Level Constraints** are for **Readability** and **Documentation**. I want to Specify the **Ord** instance of my custom data **depends** on **Enum** instance.
When I write the below code it throws an error.

```
data DayOfWeek
  = Mon | Tue | Weds | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun
  deriving (Eq, Show)    

instance Enum DayOfWeek => Ord DayOfWeek where
  compare a b = compare (fromEnum a) (fromEnum b)

instance Enum DayOfWeek where
  toEnum 1 = Mon
  toEnum 2 = Tue
  toEnum 3 = Weds
  toEnum 4 = Thu
  toEnum 5 = Fri
  toEnum 6 = Sat
  toEnum 7 = Sun

  fromEnum Mon = 1
  fromEnum Tue = 2
  fromEnum Weds = 3
  fromEnum Thu = 4
  fromEnum Fri = 5
  fromEnum Sat = 6
  fromEnum Sun = 7
```

**Error**:

```
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Enum DayOfWeek
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* In the context: Enum DayOfWeek
  While checking an instance declaration
  In the instance declaration for `Ord DayOfWeek'
```

Can we write Constraints on Concrete Types

Comment: It would be simpler to just define the `Enum` instance first, then define the `Ord` instance. Also, there is a difference between *needing* an `Enum` instance and simply *using* it to define the `Ord` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code compiles if we enable a pair of extensions, writing in the first line of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
```

Still, I think it's not worth it. I'd remove the context instead, since that is what most existing code does.

Further, I'm not sure about why do you think it's important to document the fact that one instance depends on the other. I would regard that as an implementation detail, hence something I'd like to *hide* from the user, rather than to point out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What is FlexibleContexts and can you please suggest any beginner friendly sites for learning haskell.

Comment: @PKChem Haskell was initially designed 20+ years ago so that it could handle only very simple cases like `instance C variable => C (T variable)`. Here, the context `C variable` really requires `variable` to be a type variable. This restriction and many others were removed with time. GHC by default still applies many restrictions, but allows to remove most of them through extensions. Most code nowadays exploits at least a few extensions. Flexible context allow non-variables in the context above, e.g. `instance C Char => ...`.

Comment: @PKChem The most beginner-friendly tutorial seems to be [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) right now, even if it does not cover advanced topics. Your question is not beginner level, IMO, being based on some typeclass technicality. Don't be afraid to read the [GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=flexiblecontext#extension-FlexibleContexts) on extensions. Usually it is undestandable, even if it's a bit technical, and often comes with examples.